# Getting GPU passthrough to work on WSL2 for windows 10

Tags: drivers, cuda, windows-subsystem-for-linux

My Ubuntu install is not picking up my CUDA card. I have an GTX A5000. I ran through the following steps in section 4.2.6 from this [tutorial](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/wsl-user-guide/index.html#ch03a-setting-up-cuda):

```
wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/wsl-ubuntu/x86_64/cuda-wsl-ubuntu.pin
sudo mv cuda-wsl-ubuntu.pin /etc/apt/preferences.d/cuda-repository-pin-600
wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/11.4.0/local_installers/cuda-repo-wsl-ubuntu-11-4-local_11.4.0-1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-wsl-ubuntu-11-4-local_11.4.0-1_amd64.deb
sudo apt-key add /var/cuda-repo-wsl-ubuntu-11-4-local/7fa2af80.pub
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install cuda
```

However when I try to build a sample as instructed in [section 4.2.7](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/wsl-user-guide/index.html#building-cuda-samples) I get the following error:

```
[./BlackScholes] - Starting...
CUDA error at ../../common/inc/helper_cuda.h:779 code=100(cudaErrorNoDevice) "cudaGetDeviceCount(&device_count)"
```

so WSL is not picking up my GPU. The current version of the driver I am running is 30.0.14.7239

When I run `uname -r` I get the following:

```
5.10.102.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2
```

edit:
Version of windows I am running is windows 10(OS Build 19042.1586). I opted to be in the "windows insiders" group, but I don't think this is the latest build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have it working now. After signing up for windows insiders group I had to go to windows update and go into optional updates. I added the 21H2 patch and everything seems to be happy now.