# Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS doesn't find Nvidia driver at all

Tags: drivers, nvidia, windows-subsystem-for-linux, gpu

I was trying to run a program in Ubuntu on Windows 10 but for some reason it just cannot find my NVIDA driver. I have tried install via the '`$sudo apt-get nvidia-xxx`' (tried different versions too), but it didn't seem to help.

When I do '`$nvidia-smi`' it returns '`NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.`'.
When I do '`$nvidia-settings`' it returns '`ERROR: The control display is undefined; please run` nvidia-settings --help `for usage information.`'

I have then followed some of the steps on the internet trying to do `$lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'`, the results are

```
> lspci: Unable to load libkmod resources: error -2 5ba5:00:00.0 3D
> controller: Microsoft Corporation Basic Render Driver
>         Kernel driver in use: dxgkrnl e7a1:00:00.0 3D controller: Microsoft Corporation Basic Render Driver
>         Kernel driver in use: dxgkrnl
```

alternatively if I do a `sudo lshw -C display`
results would be:

```
 *-display:0
       description: 3D controller
       product: Basic Render Driver
       vendor: Microsoft Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@5ba5:00:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=dxgkrnl latency=0
       resources: irq:0
  *-display:1
       description: 3D controller
       product: Basic Render Driver
       vendor: Microsoft Corporation
       physical id: 3
       bus info: pci@e7a1:00:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=dxgkrnl latency=0
       resources: irq:0
```

Anyone has any idea how to resolve this? Thanks in advance

PS for reference, if i do a nivida-smi on powershell it would have:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 452.39       Driver Version: 452.39       CUDA Version: 11.0     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name            TCC/WDDM | Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Quadro P620        WDDM  | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| 34%   40C    P5    N/A /  N/A |   1064MiB /  2048MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

Comment: You might want to follow through https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/enabling-gpu-acceleration-on-ubuntu-on-wsl2-with-the-nvidia-cuda-platform#1-overview

Comment: What do you mean by " run a program in Ubuntu on Windows 10". Is Ubuntu installed to some virtual environment? Then installing Nvidia drivers is not an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have things worked out using https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/enabling-gpu-acceleration-on-ubuntu-on-wsl2-with-the-nvidia-cuda-platform#1-overview which Terrance shared with me the other day! Thanks Terrance!

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned "trying to run a program in Ubuntu on Windows 10". If you run Ubuntu as a virtual machine or a guest OS, then the guest OS (Ubuntu) won't be able to see the GPU in the host OS (Windows 10) unless you have GPU pass-through enabled.

There is also a related question on GPU pass-through for WSL2:

[Getting GPU passthrough to work on WSL2 for windows 10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1399836)

, which says that the patch 21H2 is needed for GPU pass-through to work.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. Sorry but I'm a bit confused on that article, do I just add the 21H2 windows patch and this would solve the issue? Sorry if this is too basic a question...

Comment: @Cheng From what I read, GPU pass-through is a tricky issue. If you are using VirtualBox, I read that only certain combinations of AMD CPU and NVidia cards work. Intel CPUs don't. I haven't used WSL2. So I can't speak about that. The easiest solution for me was to avoid any virtualization and install Ubuntu directly (as a dualboot).